# Keras categorical cross entropy softmax input.dim_size error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, softmax

I'm developing a pretty complex pipeline where I build tf.Datasets from TFRecords files and feed those to a Keras model alongside data augmentation and many sanity checks and validations. So please, let me apologize for not being able to bring a fully reproducible example.

Anyway, I'm trying to train an image classification model, and I have my image data as 192*256 grayscale tensors, and the labels as one-hot encoded three-dimensional vectors.

a problem arises when I try to fit the model, and it appears to be from the softmax activation and/or the categorical crossentropy loss function.

```
output_len = 3
activation = 'softmax'
loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()

categorical_model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(192, 256, 1)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(output_len, activation='softmax')
])

categorical_model.summary()

categorical_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=loss)

print(aug_data[0])
print(aug_data[1])

categorical_model.fit(aug_data, steps_per_epoch = 1070, epochs=2)
```

in the above, 'aug_data[0]' is the training samples, and [1] is the labels (feeding tf.data sets to Keras requires the samples and labels be in tuples). Running the above gets me to:

```
Model: "sequential_27"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_27 (Flatten)         (None, 49152)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_54 (Dense)             (None, 128)               6291584   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_55 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 387       
=================================================================
Total params: 6,291,971
Trainable params: 6,291,971
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_26:0", shape=(?, 192, 256, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_26:1", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32)
Train on 1070 samples
Epoch 1/2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-12cc2cbea62b> in <module>()
     18 print(aug_data[1])
     19 
---> 20 categorical_model.fit(aug_data, steps_per_epoch = 1070, epochs=2)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1470         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1471                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1472                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1473         if run_metadata:
   1474           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Expected begin[0] == 0 (got 1) and size[0] == 0 (got 1) when input.dim_size(0) == 0
     [[{{node loss_27/dense_55_loss/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Slice_1}}]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Expected begin[0] == 0 (got 1) and size[0] == 0 (got 1) when input.dim_size(0) == 0
     [[{{node loss_27/dense_55_loss/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Slice_1}}]]
     [[loss_27/mul/_1495]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

I'm printing the shape of the input and label tensors (right below the model summary) to confirm that the shape is as expected. However, I'm getting this weird error that for the life of me I can't solve. With sparse cross entropy I'm getting another error, again with the batch dim.

Interestingly enough, putting binary crossentropy allows the model to run (though not learning much...).

I've never before tried to fit together tf.datasets and Keras, and it seems quite a challenge. Any input towards this would be helpful and much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: what does print(aug_data.shape) say?

Comment: I might be wrong on this one but it's possible that `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` requires shape `(None, 1, len_outputs)`. Maybe try to reshape the data and see if it works?

Comment: @Amit tuple has no shape :/ the elements of the tuple do - their shape is as in the print above

Comment: @vvalchev it expects that each element of tuple has shape = (192, 256, 1) .. Is it satisfied in your code?

Comment: @sebastian-sz no bueno :( expanded the second-to-last dimension, for label tensor shape of 'Tensor("IteratorGetNext_32:1", shape=(?, 1, 3), dtype=float32)' with the same error :(

Comment: @Amit yes, all samples have that shape

Comment: One thing I notice that you have passed X_train but you have not passed Y_Train in the following line. "categorical_model.fit(aug_data, steps_per_epoch = 1070, epochs=2)" .. May be you have to add the add the Y_train information as well.

Comment: Yes, as the answer below noted - it appears my 'knowledge' that keras expects the data & labels in tuples was incorrect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the below line of code:

```
categorical_model.fit(aug_data, steps_per_epoch = 1070, epochs=2)
```

with this line:

```
categorical_model.fit(aug_data[0], aug_data[1], steps_per_epoch = 1070, epochs=2)
```

Since the inputs for `categorical_model.fit()` function must be a tuple of `(aug_data[0], aug_data[1])` rather than an input that contains both inputs & labels stacked along 0th dimension.